# Knockout - Having trouble accessing nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

There's several similar questions about accessing nested JSON in Knockout, but I can't get this to work. I'm sure it's something simple. I'd like to do this without the knockout.mapping plugin if possible.

EDIT:

Here's a fiddle I put together. https://jsfiddle.net/ym0h4w49/14/

I can't get this to actually render the dom like it does on the site I'm working on, but the console.log shows the singleContact Object. Uncomment the self.tags to see how it breaks.

Given this JSON response with nested objects:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "Ina",
  "lastname": "Church",
  ... etc ...
  "registered": "2014-10-06T11:22:51 +05:00",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "t1",
      "contactId": 1,
      "tagLabel": "wguldin"
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I access the `tags` for this person? I've tried the following.

```
function detailViewModel(contactID) {
  var self = this;
  self.contactID = ko.observable(contactID);
  self.contact = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.getContact = function(id) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + id + '?_embed=tags&_embed=reminders',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          var contactData = new singleContact(data);
          self.contact(contactData);
        }
      });
  }

  self.getContact(self.contactID());
};
```

This view model creates a new singleContact, which processes the data like so:

```
function singleContact(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = data.firstname;
  self.lastName = data.lastname;
  ...

  self.tags = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.tags, function(tag) {
      return new tag(tag.id, tag.contactID, tag.tagLabel);
  }));
};
```

Which should then pass in the tag information to this function, I think.

```
function tag(id, contactID, tagLabel) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = id;
    self.contactID = contactID;
    self.tagLabel = tagLabel;
}
```

But when I console.log singleContact, a weird function thing appears as the `tags` value.

[image: console.log of singleContact]

I'm not sure if that means its there or not, but it doesn't render in the DOM using this markup:

```
<!-- ko foreach: contact -->
  <h1 data-bind="text: firstName"></h1>

  ...

  <!-- ko foreach: tags -->
  <p data-bind="text: tag.tagLabel"></p>
  <!-- /ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you can make up a fiddle with issue that will be helpful to get your quick ,

Comment: It isn't perfect, but I added one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

**view:**

```
<!-- ko foreach: contact -->
  <h1 data-bind="text: firstName"></h1>
  <!-- ko foreach: tags -->
  <p data-bind="text:tagLabel"></p>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**viewModel:**

```
var json = {
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "Ina",
  "lastname": "Church",
  "registered": "2014-10-06T11:22:51 +05:00",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "t1",
      "contactId": 1,
      "tagLabel": "wguldin"
    }
  ]
}

function tag(id, contactID, tagLabel) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.contactID = contactID;
    self.tagLabel = tagLabel;
}

function singleContact(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.firstName = data.firstname;
  self.lastName = data.lastname;
    var con =  ko.utils.arrayMap(data.tags, function(item) { // use item rather tag which may give different meaning & loop through data.tags 
      return new tag(item.id, item.contactID, item.tagLabel);
  });
  self.tags = ko.observableArray(con); 
};

function detailViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.contact = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.contact([new singleContact(json)]); // use [] here to make it array
};
ko.applyBindings(new detailViewModel())
```

sample working fiddle up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25383/)**

Check here for your working **[fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25384/)**

Comment: So, that worked for the tags! But, my data also has a second sub object. I tried editing your fiddle to illustrate. I would think it would just work for the second, am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25385/

Comment: a typo bro ! . you are looping through `reminder` rather `reminders`. check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25398/ . cheers

Comment: Oh man, not the first time that's happened on this project. You are super cool. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i think thats fine i think all you need to do is change the knockout binding

```
<!-- ko foreach: contact -->
  <h1 data-bind="text: firstName"></h1>

  ...

  <!-- ko foreach: tags() -->
  <p data-bind="text: tag().tagLabel"></p>
  <!-- /ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: That didn't have any effect ... sorry!

Comment: in your console log can you watch it but put `()` after it to see what datas in there